# using node-usb this.open() , LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, libusb, node-usb

After connecting the USB to the raspberry pie,

I have loaded the devices with node-usb .

The desired device was found by the device's VID and PID.

Then I open the device and try to read the data.

But this._open () , error: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS I get this error occured.

How do I give permission?

I did not solve it even though I tried this.

```
fs.chmod('/media/pi/EFD0-AA20', 511);
```

below is my code.

```
usb.on('attach', function(device) {

    var devices = usb.getDeviceList();
    var sandisk_ultrafit = usb.findByIds(1921, 21891);
    sandisk_ultrafit.open();

});
```

Comment: Have you tried running with sudo? Or giving the correct USB permissions in udev?

Comment: i tried but error say no such file or directory. above path is mounte point.

Answer (score 0):

1. cd /etc/udev/rules.d
2. Create a file named "myVender.rules"
3. SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="--VID--", MODE="0666"
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="--VID--", MODE="0666"
4. replace "--VID--" with the vender ID of your device (USB device)

**In My Linux Machine**

5. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Kd3.png)
6. **VID** of my usb is **0781**

Comment: Any idea, How to do this for Windows?